# How to update a column value from a pivot table of a selected user?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am new to pivot tables and laravel and I'm having a hard time updating a certain column of my pivot table. I tried searching online but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to update the status column of the selected user. Note as an admin i can view the customers profile and update their information. Here's what i have:

customers  table

> id | name | budget

products table

> id | name | price

customer_product pivot table

> product_id | customer_id | qty | status

Product model

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany('App\Customer', 'product_customer')
    ->withPivot('status','qty');

}
```

Customer Model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', product_customer)
    ->where('status', '=', '1')
    ->withPivot('qty', 'status');
}
```

Controller
This is where i'm having trouble with, after the updateExistingPivot it requires an $id, how can i place the $id of the current customer profile that i am currently viewing or am i understanding it the wrong way. The code runs but it doesn't do anything. It doesn't update the status column. I want to be able to change status from 1 to 0.

```
public function updateProductStatus($id)
 {
  Product::find($id)->customers()->updateExistingPivot($id, array('status' => 0), false);
 }  

public function getCustomerProfile($id)
{
  $customers = Customer::find($id);
  foreach ($customers->products as $product) 
  {
    $product->pivot->product_customer;
  } 
  $products = Product::lists('name');
  return view('admin.customer-profile', ['customers' => $customers], compact('products') );
}  

public function index()
{
  $customers = DB::table('customers')
  ->select('name')
  ->get();
  return view('admin.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

Route

```
Route::put('updateProductStatus/{id}', ['as' => 'updateProductStatus',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@updateProductStatus']);
Route::get('getCustomerProfile/{id}', ['as' => 'getCustomerProfile',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@getCustomerProfile']);
```

Blade

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
         <tr>   
          <th>Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Status</th>                                         
         </tr>
        </thead>
            @foreach($customers->products as $product)
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
              <td>{{$product->pivot->qty}}</td>
              <td>{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['updateProductStatus', $product->pivot->status], 'method'=>'PUT'))!!}
              {!!Form::button('Update', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'type'=>'submit'])!!}
              {!!Form::close()!!}<td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            @endforeach
</table>
```

main.blade.php

```
<table id="datable_1" class="table table-hover display  pb-30" >
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
   @foreach($customers as $customer)
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
       <td>{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['deleteCustomerProfile', $customer->id], 'method'=>'DELETE'))!!}
           {{ link_to_route('getCustomerProfile', 'Edit', [$customer->id] , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}|
           {!!Form::button('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'type'=>'submit'])!!}
           {!!Form::close()!!}
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        @endforeach
       </table>
```

URL of the blade above

> /admin/getCustomerProfile/1

Error

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#19 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:218
#18 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:methodNotAllowed in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:205
#17 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:getRouteForMethods in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:158
#16 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:821
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:691
#14 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:675
#13 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:246
#12 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52
#11 call_user_func in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52
#10 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:44
#9 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136
#8 call_user_func_array in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32
#6 call_user_func in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32
#5 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103
#4 call_user_func in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103
#3 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:132
#2 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:99
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\public\index.php:54
#0 require_once in G:\xampp\htdocs\theshop\server.php:21
```

Comment: Are you viewing the products for a single customer or for multiple customers in your blade.php file?

Comment: @NikolaGavric oh im viewing only the product for a single costumer.

Comment: When you say product, you mean multiple products for a single customer?

Comment: @NikolaGavric yes a single costumer can have multiple products. Sorry i'll edit my post, i'll post the blade where it displayed all the costumers and ill include the route for viewing costumer profile.

Comment: No need, I've updated my answer, note that the $customer in the blade.php file should be of type `\App\Customer`

Comment: @NikolaGavric okay i edited just in case you needed to check it.

Comment: Ive updated my answer again to reflect your other stuff @JesseRodriguez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble with the updateExistingPivot() function because it updates the status for all the rows with the same customer id. So instead i just used DB update. Here's my solution

```
public function updateProductStatus($id)
{
 DB::table('customer_product')
 ->where('product_id', $id)
 ->update(['status' => 0]);
 return redirect()->back();
}
```

and in my blade i just changed

```
{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['updateProductStatus', $product->pivot->status], 'method'=>'PUT'))!!}
```

into

```
{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['updateProductStatus', $product->pivot->product_id], 'method'=>'PUT'))!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post a full explanation and solution..

You are strongly encouraged to change the method name `belongstoMany` to 
 `belongsToMany`, but this is optional thanks to @amphetamachine check the comments for an explanation why.

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Customer', 'customer_product')
               ->withPivot('status', 'qty');

}
```

Your controller code

```
use App\Customer;
use App\Product;
...
...
public function updateProductStatus(Customer $customer, Product $product)
{
  $pivotProduct = $customer->products()->wherePivot('product_id', $product->id);
  $pivotProduct->updateExistingPivot($customer->id, array('status' => $pivotProduct->pivot->status == 0 ? 1:0));
}

public function getCostumerProfile(Customer $customer)
{
  return view('admin.costumer-profile', ['customer' => $customer]);
}

public function index()
{
  $customers = Customer::all();
  return view('admin.index', ['customers' => $customers]);
}
```

Your routes file now includes those 2 parameters you are receiving and they are `customer` and `product` and thanks to [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) they will be auto-resolved to their respective objects

```
Route::put('updateProductStatus/{customer}/{product}', ['as' => 'updateProductStatus',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@updateProductStatus']);

Route::get('getCostumerProfile/{customer}', ['as' => 'getCostumerProfile',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getCostumerProfile']);
```

Your blade file should first iterate through all of the customers and for each of the customer it will iterate through all of his/her products and show them in a table, consider that you can change the design of the table

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>   
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Status</th>                                         
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @if($customer->products()->count() > 0)
      @foreach($customer->products as $product)
         <tr>
            <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->pivot->qty}}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::open(array('route' => ['updateProductStatus', ['customer' => $customer, 'product' => $product]], 'method'=>'PUT'))!!}
            {!!Form::button('Update', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'type'=>'submit'])!!}
            {!!Form::close()!!}<td>
         </tr>
      @endforeach
      @else
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No products found for this customer.</td>
         </tr>
      @endif
      </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally your `main.blade.php` should look like this

```
<table id="datable_1" class="table table-hover display  pb-30" >
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  @foreach($customers as $customer)
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
        <td>{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['deleteCostumerProfile', $customer->id], 'method'=>'DELETE'))!!}
        {{ link_to_route('getCostumerProfile', 'Edit', ['customer' => $customer->id] , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}|
        {!!Form::button('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'type'=>'submit'])!!}
        {!!Form::close()!!}
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: Your first point is incorrect; in PHP, function calls are case-insensitive. Weird, I know.

Comment: @NikolaGavric sorry late reply was editing the code with yours. I got an error when viewing the profile. It says undefined variable:costumer.

Comment: Ye I just saw your other files and figured they need more fixing, will post the update soon

Comment: @NikolaGavric When I'm opening the main.blade.php I'm getting Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string error.

Comment: `{{ link_to_route('getCostumerProfile', 'Edit', [$costumer] , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}|` change that to `{{ link_to_route('getCostumerProfile', 'Edit', ['customer' => $costumer->id] , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}|`

Comment: @NikolaGavric that solved the stdClass, but when i click my Edit, Array to string conversion this appears.

Comment: I've updated the answer, change `main.blade.php` and take a look at controllers, i've changed the `index` function

Comment: @NikolaGavri ive updated it with your changes, but the array to string conversion still appears when i click edit.

Comment: Can you update your question with the image of your error stacktrace? @jesserodriguez

Comment: @NikolaGavric i was able to solve the array to string error, i replaced Form::open into Form::model. I used it on the other blade as well and your previous code which was 'customer' => $customer now works. Another problem occured, i can now view the customer profile, but when i pressed the button to update the status it gives methodnotallowedexception.

Comment: Could you print screen the whole error and give me a link? @jesserodriguez

Comment: @NikolaGavric i edited the question, i posted the stack trace. If you need anything just inform me.

Comment: Change the `method'=>'PUT` on your form in your customer profile blade view to `'method'=>'POST'` and then change the `Route::put` to `Route::post` inside of your routes

Comment: @NikolaGavric still the same, methodnotallowedexception.

Comment: Actually, try putting `{{ link_to_route('getCostumerProfile', 'Edit', ['customer' => $costumer->id] , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}|` outside of `Form::model(`, for example just before it

Comment: @NikolaGavric sorry for the late replies. I updated and i can still view the customer profile even if its outside the form model. But i still can't update the status value, i think it's stuck on the blade part with the methodnotallowed error and it doesn't proceed to the controller function.

Comment: Can you send me a pm so we can resolve it in the chat instead of spamming comments section?

Comment: @NikolaGavric sorry wasn't able to communicate much earlier. I'm sorry to trouble you for too long with this subject so i decided to work on it and made a work around instead.